# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges - while creating new user

Tags: forms, oracle-apex

I have situation where user will create a new users and give a grant to them but I was unable to create a new user via `Apex`.
[image]

I logged in through `system` and I have already given a grant to create user to system via backend. My granting command looks like

`grant create user to system with admin option;` but unable to grant.

But if I logged in through `SQL Command Line` and create a new user it allowed me to create but not via `Apex`

[image]

What am I doing wrong please help me out.

**Note** I am using apex form to add a new user

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the connection being used via APEX has not re-connected since the grant was issued. If possible try to `SELECT * FROM SESSIONS_PRIVS` and `SESSION_ROLES` to see what grants are active. You might also like to to try (temporarily) seeing if granting DBA to the APEX user overcomes this, and if so, you would need to delve deeper as to what other privilege contained within the DBA role is required if you want to avoid giving them full DBA privs.

Comment: Where should I run that command. Since it comes with the error `table or view does not exist`

Comment: I would write a test page in your APEX app that lists the results of these queries , since that is the environment that is having the issue. You can run it in SQLPLUS as the same user and then compare the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database user named `SYSTEM` *owns* the database. It can create users without you granting it that privilege.

Saying that you logged in (to Apex) as `system`: I'd suggest you not to do that. Leave both `SYS` and `SYSTEM` alone. They are *special*, you don't want to mess up with them.

Create a new user (through SQL*Plus), grant it `create user` privilege and use it for such a purpose. Just for testing, that's what I did with the `HR` user:

- I have Apex 4.0.2 which comes with Oracle 11g XE.
- There's the `HR` database user for which I've created an Apex workspace.
- Logged in to Apex as `HR`, I created a page with a single item: `P3_USERNAME` and a button
- then I created a process that fires when I push the button. The process looks like this:

  ```
  begin
    execute immediate 'create user ' || :P3_USERNAME || ' identified by x';
  end;
  ```
- ran the page, entered `xxx` into the item and pressed a button.
- checked `ALL_USERS` and - here it is; user `xxx` is here

Try to do the same. Should be OK.